# Manually driving the PC internal speaker

Tags: audio, speaker

Is there any way, in any language (C preferred) to interface the PC internal speaker directly under Windows/Linux? (no DOS) I don't want to drive it at a specficic frequency for a given duration (no *beep(frq, msecs)*), but I'd rather send signals directly.

I suppose it's one bit resolution, so I plan using PWM driving to play wave sounds.

Comment: Note an increasing number of PCs don't have an internal speaker.

Comment: That's at least 2 questions you have embedded there as windows commands will be (potentially) quite different from linux commands.  Plus, I suspect that a good old fashioned search would deliver your information expeditiously.

Comment: Sure, I just want to have some fun hacking, and my PC does have internal speaker.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I don't care if it's either Windows or Linux, I use both OSes, I just included that in the question because I suspect it might be easier in Linux than Windows and I'd be happy with any answer. Should I edit it out or ask two different questions for the same matter? I've been searching enough too, but I just get pages about the beep() command (which is not what I want) or older DOS alternatives (which don't work anymore under Windows.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux, you will probably want to make a kernel driver to drive the speaker, and provide eg. a /dev entry for accessing it.

Note that there is already a driver that supports PCM in the Linux kernel, that interfaces as an ALSA driver. Check it out: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.39/sound/drivers/pcsp/

The actual hardware interfacing appears to be done in pscp_input.c: `pcspkr_do_sound(...)`

Comment: I'll take a look at this and the source code, looks fun, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

It's an interruption, you can embeed that in any kind of languaje that allows ASM inside it's code. Or you can just write a small program in pascal and call it.
I don't remember the interruption but a fast search will get you that info.

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](http://www.webcitation.org/query?url=http://www.geocities.com/stssppnn/pcsp.html&date=2009-10-25+22:26:34) off the wikipedia references for pc-speakers

might be useful :)